# What is the cheapest way to deploy a React app using Next.js SSR on AWS?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, next.js

I understand that [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) is a Node.js framework that requires server capabilities and therefore, using it for [server-side rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting#Server-side_rendering) (SSR) could not be hosted on an [S3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_S3) instance only.

However, does that mean that the only alternative is to host the entire app on an [EC2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud) instance, which is significantly more expensive, or is there another midway solution?

Comment: Amplify Hosting supports apps created using the Next.js framework. When you deploy your app, Amplify automatically detects SSR–you do not have to perform any manual configuration in the AWS Management Console. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/server-side-rendering-amplify.html

Answer (score 75, accepted):

#### Next.js SSR + Serverless framework + AWS Lambda

For deploying your Next.js SSR App, instead of following a traditional approach of managing and running a whole AWS EC2 instance which keeps running 24x7, there is actually one more cost-effective and modern approach which uses AWS lambda and the *Serverless* framework.

**Q. What is [AWS lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/)?** 
AWS Lambda lets you run code without provisioning or managing servers. You pay only for the compute time you consume.

**Q. What is the [*Serverless* framework](https://www.serverless.com/open-source/)?**
*Serverless Framework Open Source* lets you develop applications with a [serverless architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serverless_computing) and deploy using AWS Lambda, Azure Functions, Google CloudFunctions, and more.

**Q. What is [Serverless-Next.js](https://github.com/danielcondemarin/serverless-next.js)?**
This is a Serverless component built just for deploying a Next.js app. Also, any of your assets in the static or public folders are uploaded to S3 and served from [CloudFront](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_CloudFront) automatically, so I think this is what you are exactly looking for.

Below is the architecture explaining how it serves your app to the user.

[image]

If you are new to serverless framework, I will suggest you to go through a free course by the *Serverless* community called [Serverless for Frontend Developers](https://www.serverless.com/learn/courses/serverless-for-frontend-developers/)

@super7egazi put forward a genuine concern in the comment below. Thankfully there are a few ways to keep the Lambda function warm. This is the act of sending scheduled ping events to your functions to keep them alive and idle, ready to serve requests.

You will find various methods and plugins to achieve this, if you just search "How to keep lambda functions warm?" on Google.

Below are some links which I'm attaching for reference.

[How to keep your lambda functions warm?](https://acloudguru.com/blog/engineering/how-to-keep-your-lambda-functions-warm)

[How to Minimize AWS Lambda Cold Starts](https://epsagon.com/development/how-to-minimize-aws-lambda-cold-starts/)

[Keep your lambdas warm](https://www.serverless.com/blog/keep-your-lambdas-warm)

Comment: @Thanh-QuyNguyen I have updated my answer with slightly better explanation. Also if you ever try deploying your Next.js app on AWS lambda using serverless-next.js, and if you happen to save some credits/money over time, then don't forget to mark this answer as accepted. :D

Comment: I've actually been working on this all day before you answer and yes, this seems to be the most cost-effective way to deploy a NextJS app to AWS. However, I've been encountering an issue with next-i18n which is currently not working with Serverless. The team is on it though, and it's in the beta. I just didn't have enough time to make it work today 

Comment: Oh that's great. And I see Serverless framework is yet to mature. I never worked with next-i18n library, but I hope they come up with a fix for it very soon.

Comment: Great answer! one thing to keep in mind that this architecture is cheap, but it is not good for SEO. AWS lambda goes into cold mode which means that if no one is hitting the site, the first hit to the site will take longer time to finish. For example, Google crawler can hit the site when it has been unused for some time, and your site will respond in longer than usual time because it is the first call after it has been idle. Just keep this in mind if SEO is important for you.

Comment: Concerning SEO - if you deploy NextJS to a VPS (AWS, Digital Ocean, Heroku etc) AKA not on vercel, the nextJS server will act like a regular express server. So the API routes will just be regular API endpoints. No cold start issue

Comment: As we can only deploy 250mb code into lambda, when project grows and we are using many node modules. How we can handle such scenario?

Comment: You can also deploy Next.js apps to your AWS account using CDK with the SST framework. Compatible with Next.js 11. Here's an example https://serverless-stack.com/examples/how-to-create-a-nextjs-app-with-serverless.html

Comment: Can it be used freely for a company based repo? I am confused by their pricing docs which mentions this as `Personal Github Organizations only`. Not sure what orgs mean here. Do they mean  personal accounts only?

Comment: Found this package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/lambda-warmer that uses the same technique mentioned in the blog to keep lambda warm.

Answer (score 43):

#### AWS Next.js Terraform module

We created an open source [Terraform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terraform_(software)) module as a lower cost alternative to the *Serverless* framework for this use case. Instead of relying only on [Lambda@Edge](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/edge/) for all [SSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting#Server-side_rendering) operations, we use Lambda@Edge only for routing (as some kind of reverse proxy) and then redirect the request internally via API Gateway to an regional [Lambda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWS_Lambda).

Since we use [CloudFront](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_CloudFront) as a reverse proxy, we can also split most of the requests for static files against `_next/static/*` for CSS, JavaScript, etc. and serve them directly by [S3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_S3) without touching the Lambda@Edge proxy at all.

[image]

So the cost per request are different per route:

- **Requests for static assets**: CSS, JavaScript, and images

  Only [costs for CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/) and [costs for S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/)) (for misses from CloudFront) apply
- **Requests for HTML**: Prerendered HTML-Routes or Routes that need server-side rendering (SSR)

  [Costs for Cloudfront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/), [costs for Lambda@Edge](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/#Lambda.40Edge_Pricing) (proxy, metered at 1 ms steps) apply.

  - **Rewrite routes that serve pre-rendered HTML**

    [Costs for S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) apply.
  - **Routes that use server-side rendering (SSR)**

    [Costs for HTTP API-Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/pricing/#HTTP_APIs) and [costs for regional Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/) (SSR, metered in 1 ms steps) apply.

The total costs are usually far below US$0.50 / month for a few thousand requests with this model, while having a fast-serving site powered by CloudFront edge caching.

Find more information in the GitHub repository: *[Terraform Next.js module for AWS](https://github.com/dealmore/terraform-aws-next-js)*

Comment: Why is it cheaper to render the static assets on lambda as lambda@edge?

Answer (score 17):

### Next.js + *Serverless* is not free.

Next.js + *Serverless* is currently deployed on [Lambda@Edge](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/edge/) which is **not free**. You do not enjoy the free tier from [Lambda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWS_Lambda) (not Lambda@Edge).

### [Vercel](https://github.com/vercel/vercel) + Next.js is free

If you have a low traffic website, I would recommend you to deploy it with Vercel.com which uses Lambda (AWS Network) on the backend.

*Their hobby version is free and gives generous free traffic and invocation **comparable** to AWS Lambda Free tier.

Deployment of a Next.js application is as easy as uploading to GitHub + Vercel's auto deployment with GitHub integration. You do not need to bother about [S3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_S3), or hosting or your static files. Everything gets hosted on Vercel the moment you push to GitHub. You just need to concentrate on development.

When your requirement goes up (you go past the *Hobby* package, and you go past the *Pro* package), then it becomes more cost-effective deploying on Serverless@Edge.

By then, all you need to do is to switch your domain over.

### Just deploy it on a VPS

Serverless is a nice concept, and the ability to launch your websites for free on various platform is a plus.

However, cold start can be a big problem as it sometimes takes 3-4 seconds to load a page for your visitor.

This is not so much of a problem if you are doing static ***or*** static incremental generation. **It just** ***isn't any good*** **for getServerSideProps**.

If you are struggling for cold starts, trust me and move on to a VPS. A US$5 VPS can run a site pretty well.

Comment: when you deploy to a VPS, are the files inside the `api` folder just regular server endpoints (which is what I hope)

I read somewhere that if you deploy to vercel, the api endpoints are turned to serverless functions.

Comment: when u deploy to VPS, yes it runs like how you work with "next dev", everything is serve from your VPS with no speed penalty. You need to start the app with "next build" and "next start", or manage it with "PM2"

Comment: It's worth mentioning that free Vercel hobby plans are limited to personal, non-commercial use. More info: https://vercel.com/docs/platform/fair-use-policy#commercial-usage

Answer (score 7):

You can use AWS Lightsail: https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/

In my experience with `nextjs` the cloud functions are not a good place to deploy a large application, so, this would be your options:

0. Only go with cloud functions if your app is super small and is never gonna grow. Cloud functions have limitations on file size, dependencies, bundle size, etc, etc, etc
1. AWS Lightsail: https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/ and a small VPS that you can set up yourself with Nginx and node. Is like $5 / month and you can use your credits.
2. Same as number 1, but on Digital Ocean.
3. AWS Ec2

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure if you have a requirement to host on Amazon or not, but you can host on [DigitalOcean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DigitalOcean) for US$5/month, or you can host on the free tier for Heroku until you are confident you want to move to Amazon. You can later move to a more expensive solution and host of [EC2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud):

- [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing) That will give you 1 GB memory, 25 GB SSD, and 1 TB transfer for US$5/month
- [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/pricing). That will give you 512 MB memory and - one Web and one Worker Dyno for free, and even if you will pay, there are some affordable prices and [Heroku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroku) is a managed service, so they will take care of everything and you don't have to set up anything

I believe that should be a good start for you before pay for more expensive solutions.

And that answer for your questions, *yes*, EC2 is the cheapest for Amazon and [Elastic Beanstalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWS_Elastic_Beanstalk) if you prefer a more managed solution within Amazon.

Comment: I actually have "free AWS credits" for a limited amount of time, hence my question. So there is no way to handle the SSR on a let's say "limited EC2" and the static part on an S3 server? The "only" option using only AWS would be going all in on an EC2?

Answer (score 4):

To deploy our Next.js website, we have been using [AWS Lambda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWS_Lambda): *[Serverless Next.js Component](https://github.com/serverless-nextjs/serverless-next.js)*
It was amazingly simple to use it.
Unfortunately, sometimes the load of the page was very slow. It was from 2 seconds to 7 seconds.
It was also confirmed by the Google Search console.

[image]

We could not find a way to really deep dive this issue and how we were able to solve this, but I suspect a cold start. After some research, AWS said it was theoretically possible to solve it with concurrency:

*[New for AWS Lambda – Predictable start-up times with Provisioned Concurrency](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-for-aws-lambda-predictable-start-up-times-with-provisioned-concurrency/)*

But I could not manage to make it work, as it is a [Lambda@Edge](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/edge/) instance and it is also very expensive!

[image]

At [NachoNacho](http://nachonacho.com) we focus on [SEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization), so the time to load the page was our biggest concern.

We finally decided to move to a simple [AWS EC2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud).

Here you have the comparison:

[image]

Source: [Site24x7](https://www.site24x7.com/)

[image]

- Light blue: EC2
- Dark Blue: Lambda image image

Source: [Dareboost](https://www.dareboost.com/)

Comment: Is it possible that your Lambda was cold? I believe there are ways to keep it hot to prevent situations like the above

Comment: There are ways to keep a container warm. However, the idea of serverless functions is that it can spin up several containers to server connection spike. You can keep one container warm but you cannot keep all the containers warm.

Comment: @Alan when you moved to AWS ec2 what was the full infrastructure stack? How you implement and achieved "Incremental Static Regeneration"?

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration